# Как запустить javascript при попадании на экран определенного блока?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы анимация баров начиналась не после загрузки страницы, а когда пользователь доскролит до блока #skillsbar, в котором они расположены.

https://codepen.io/minimalweb/pen/QmNQZg

```
//draw the doughnut
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){var doughnutArray = [document.getElementById('doughnut').getContext('2d'), document.getElementById('doughnut2').getContext('2d'), document.getElementById('doughnut3').getContext('2d'), document.getElementById('doughnut4').getContext('2d')];
for (var i = 0; i < doughnutArray.length; i++) {
  doughnutArray[i].lineWidth = 10; //thickness of the line
  doughnutArray[i].fillStyle = '#3c4761';
  doughnutArray[i].strokeStyle = "#ccc";
  doughnutArray[i].beginPath();
  doughnutArray[i].arc(70, 70, 65, 4.72, 15, false); //.arc(x, y , radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
  doughnutArray[i].stroke();
}}, false);

window.onload = function() {
    loadSkills1();
    loadSkills2();
    loadSkills3();
    loadSkills4();
  }
  /*Load skills one function*/
function loadSkills1() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('skill1').getContext('2d');
  var al = 0;
  var start = 4.72;
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  var diff;

  function progressSim() {
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2); //change the arc by multiplying .. * Math.PI*2* --> 7.5=75, 5=50 etc.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10; //thickness of the line
    ctx.fillStyle = '#3c4761';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#30bae7";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = "30px Titillium Web";
    ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5 + 2, ch * .5 + 8, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(70, 70, 65, start, diff / 10 + start, false); //.arc(x, y , radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
    ctx.stroke();
    if (al >= 90) { // stop the recreation at your desired point, i.e change 100 to 75 if you need just 75%.
      clearTimeout(sim);
      // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
    }
    al++;
  }
  var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 20); //speed   
}
/*loadSkills2 function*/
function loadSkills2() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('skill2').getContext('2d');
  var al = 0;
  var start = 4.72;
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  var diff;

  function progressSim() {
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2); //change the arc by multiplying .. * Math.PI*2* --> 7.5=75, 5=50 etc.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10; //thickness of the line
    ctx.fillStyle = '#3c4761';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#d74680";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = "30px Titillium Web";
    ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5 + 2, ch * .5 + 8, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(70, 70, 65, start, diff / 10 + start, false); //.arc(x, y , radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
    ctx.stroke();
    if (al >= 75) { // stop the recreation at your desired point, i.e change 100 to 75 if you need just 75%.
      clearTimeout(sim);
      // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
    }
    al++;
  }
  var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 30); //speed
}

/* loadSkill3 function*/
function loadSkills3() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('skill3').getContext('2d');
  var al = 0;
  var start = 4.72;
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  var diff;

  function progressSim() {
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2); //change the arc by multiplying .. * Math.PI*2* --> 7.5=75, 5=50 etc.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10; //thickness of the line
    ctx.fillStyle = '#3c4761';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#15c7a8";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = "30px Titillium Web";
    ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5 + 2, ch * .5 + 8, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(70, 70, 65, start, diff / 10 + start, false); //.arc(x, y , radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
    ctx.stroke();
    if (al >= 70) { // stop the recreation at your desired point, i.e change 100 to 75 if you need just 75%.
      clearTimeout(sim);
      // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
    }
    al++;
  }
  var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 40); //speed
}
/* loadSkill4 function*/
function loadSkills4() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('skill4').getContext('2d');
  var al = 0;
  var start = 4.72;
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
  var diff;

  function progressSim() {
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2); //change the arc by multiplying .. * Math.PI*2* --> 7.5=75, 5=50 etc.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10; //thickness of the line
    ctx.fillStyle = '#3c4761';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#eb7d4b";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = "30px Titillium Web";
    ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5 + 2, ch * .5 + 8, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(70, 70, 65, start, diff / 10 + start, false); //.arc(x, y , radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
    ctx.stroke();
    if (al >= 85) { // stop the recreation at your desired point, i.e change 100 to 75 if you need just 75%.
      clearTimeout(sim);
      // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
    }
    al++;
  }
  var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50); //speed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var footer = document.getElementById("footer");

document.onscroll = function() {
var top = footer.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var heightScreen = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var g = top - heightScreen;
if (g <=0){
 body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
} else if (g >0){
 body.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
}
```

```css
body{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-around;
}

div{
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```